# visual fadeout is not happening

Tags: jquery, css

I do fade out of the element, it seems it works on some level but transparent doesn't apply to a table row and tr just removes in the end.

```
    $('input:checked[name*="bulk"]').each(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(1800);
    })
```

Can that be caused because of css style?

UPDATE
http://jsfiddle.net/EsdR2/1/

Comment: Again, works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jVnW6/). Please add some HTML markup and CSS.

Comment: I have added fidle link please check

Comment: It looks good and like expected. It fades out the element and it disappears completely in a last step. Do you want a different behavior?

Comment: I stand corrected. Opera deals with the opacity differently. I hope my answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Opera doesn't support CSS `opacity` on `<tr>`-elements. You can see it in this [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5gUN/) I've created.

What you could to, to make it work as expected in Opera too, is to fade out all the `<td>`-elements within the selected row. Afterwards the row will also collapse, like it does in other browsers when fading out the `<tr>` directly. To update your fiddle change `$this.closest('tr').fadeOut(1800);` to:

```
$this.closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1800);
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/tbAHk/)

Answer (score 0):

I've also found problem in animating table elements directly, try to wrap each row in a div like:

```
<div>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</div>
```

and fade out the div

```
$(this).closest('div').fadeOut(1800);
```

Comment: <tr> stands for table row, they are supposed to be in a <table>, <tbody>, <thead> or <tfoot> element. Not wrapped in a div. In fact, it's likely that the render engine will remove the <div>. Webkit does, check this fiddle [jsfiddle.net/EsdR2/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/EsdR2/7/) and look at the output or inspect the table : webkit automatically adds a <tbody> and kicks the <div> out.