# I need to wrap up table row into div

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap up table row into div, I do

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    $(this).insertBefore('<div>');
    $(this).insertAfter('</div>');
})
```

but seems doesn't work
UPDATE
fidle http://jsfiddle.net/EsdR2/1/

Comment: You should not be doing that... is not a valid HTMl markup... Rows can not be wraped by divs.

Comment: it will be a invalid html

Comment: in theory it will be `$('table tr').wrap('<div />')`

Comment: Why do you think you need to wrap them in divs?  What exactly is it you are trying to do?

Comment: fadeOut doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560061/visual-fadeout-is-not-happening?noredirect=1#comment27305312_18560061

Comment: You cannot use **DOM** manipulation methods to add **HTML fragments**.

Comment: You can't solve the `fadeOut` problem by wrapping a table row in a div; you need to completely replace the table and rows with `display:block` divs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are trying to break them into separate section for so than a row, then maybe try the tbody approach.

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody class="first-part">
        <tr>
            <td>first</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="second-part" style="display:none">
        <tr>
            <td>second</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit after seeing fade out then you can try this javascript..

```
var firstPart = $('tbody.first-part');
var secondPart = $('tbody.second-part');

$('#SomeButton').click(function () {
    firstPart.fadeOut("fast");
    secondPart.fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Here a jsFiddle with fadeout working.  http://jsfiddle.net/u3fNL/1/

Comment: Seems to working for me in chrome.  I click delete and row fades out.