# How to make Jquery sortable plugin use more than one row in a table for dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table that represents button. Each Button has three properties. To represent this structure i am using table where the first row is the name of the button and then the three properties of the button follows in the next three rows. Now i want to enable the user to reorder buttons. For this i am using JQUERY Sortable plugin. It makes the tbody sortable and I can drag and drop individual rows.

WHat i want is that instead of dragging and dropping individual rows the user should be able to drag four rows together in a group ( The name + properties of the button)
How can this be achieved.

I have the table in the beginning like this

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight"
    id="tab_logic">
    <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
```

And I am appending the rows in this manner

```html
function loadTable(num) {
   $('#tab_logic').empty();
   
   for (var i=1 ;i<=num;i++)   {  
   $('#tab_logic').append("<div class = 'editrow'>");
   $('#tab_logic').append("<tr class='321'><td colspan='3' align='center'><p id='addrp"+i+"'><strong>Action Button "+i+" Properties</strong></p></td></tr>");
   $('#tab_logic').append("<tr class='123'><td align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addac"+i+"'><strong>Action</strong></p></td><td class='text-danger' align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addpac"+i+"'>Action</p></td><td><input type ='text' class ='form-control' id='addiac"+i+"' name ='addiac"+i+"' placeholder='Enter Action'</td> </tr>");
   $('#tab_logic').append("<tr class='123'><td align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addat"+i+"'><strong>Action Text</strong></p></td><td class='text-danger' align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addpat"+i+"'>Action Text</p></td><td><input type ='text' class ='form-control' id='addiat"+i+"' name ='addiat"+i+"' placeholder='Enter Action Text'</td> </tr>");
   $('#tab_logic').append("<tr class='123'><td align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addcc"+i+"'><strong>Color Code</strong></p></td><td class='text-danger' align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addpcc"+i+"'>Color Code</p></td><td><input type ='text' class ='form-control' id='addicc"+i+"' name ='addicc"+i+"' placeholder='Enter Color Code'</td> </tr>");
   $('#tab_logic').append("</div>");
   
   }
   
  }
```

I want the lines running in the loop to be sortable as one instead of individually
Further using the jQuery UI sortable function like this as suggested

```html
$("#tab_logic").sortable({
    items: "div",
        helper: "clone"
    }).disableSelection();
```

But it is not working as required. I have also tried other possible combinations for items attribute but they didn't work too.

Comment: First of all stack snippets don't run JSP. You need to share the generated HTML, and a [mcve] without all the irrelevant code (You even posted commented code so what you've posted is a code dump). Secondly you need to make it clear whether you're using jQuery UI sortable or jQuery sortable plugin, and fix the tags.

Comment: @TJ Well the generted html is nothing but a select tag and most of it is generated after the user selects the option . So i just thought it would be more helpful if i post the entire code so as to see how the table is being generated . And i am using The JQUERY UI sortable .

Comment: If you expect answers only from people running a Java server, and not from the majority of jQuery community, then feel free to keep the JSP code. But like I said, the AJAX call, commented code and stuff is not related to this problem. So you need to reduce the amount of code and post [mcve] (Just a table with your buttons and the existing sorting functionality and nothing else).

Comment: @TJ I edited the question . I hope this would be suffice .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi take a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

You can wrap each 4 rows in tbody tag and can set sortable items to tbody.

```
//initialization 
$( ".table" ).sortable();
// Setter
$( ".table" ).sortable( "option", "items", ".sort-able-tbody" );
```

pls check this codepen. http://codepen.io/shahidbasheer/pen/WxRgOe

Update: you can not wrap table rows in div tag because its not a valid html. ref [I need to wrap up table row into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617815/i-need-to-wrap-up-table-row-into-div)

Comment: The codepen is great to try and understand how it works, thanks!